# Use a javascript function in a generated html code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programming a simple html form with generated code from javascript.
When i run the code in HTML itself it works, but when i put the script in a separate file, it doesn't work anymore. I tried to change the onclick event, generate the code in html, giving my elements a class and add a eventlistner to that, but nothing worked.

this is a part of my javascript code

```
    function print(){
        for (var j =0;j<3;j++){
            document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML="";
            for (var i = 0; i<omschList.length;i++){
                var li = document.createElement("LI");
                if (j==0){
                    li.innerHTML = (idlist[j+3][i]+"<object align=\"right\" onclick=\"verwijder("+i+")\"><u>verwijder</u></object>");
                } else {
                    li.innerHTML = (idlist[j+3][i]);
                }
                document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
            }
        }
    }
     function verwijder(index){
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
            idlist[i+3].splice(index, 1);
        }
        print();
    }
```

**EDIT**
the full javascript code

```
    (function ($) {

$( document ).ready( function() {

    /* VIEWPORT FIXES (http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/) */
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
      var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style');
      msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
          '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'
        )
      );
      document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }


    document.getElementById("factuurFormSend").onclick = addLine;
      var omschList=[];
      var uurprList=[];
      var aantalList=[];
      var idlist=["omschrijving",
                  "uurprijs",
                  "aantal",
                  omschList,
                  uurprList,
                  aantalList]
    function addLine(){
        omschList.push(document.getElementById("formOmschrijving").value);
        uurprList.push(document.getElementById("formUurprijs").value);
        aantalList.push(document.getElementById("formUren").value);
        print()
    }

        /*print de lijnen verticaal uit*/
    function print(){
        for (var j =0;j<3;j++){
            document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML="";
            for (var i = 0; i<omschList.length;i++){
                var li = document.createElement("LI");
                if (j==0){
                    li.innerHTML = (idlist[j+3][i]+"<object align=\"right\" onclick=\"verwijder("+i+")\"><u>verwijder</u></object>");
                } else {
                    li.innerHTML = (idlist[j+3][i]);
                }
                document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
            }
        }
        /*bereken lijntotaal*/
        document.getElementById("lijntotaal").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML=""
        var subtotaal=0;
        for (var i=0; i<uurprList.length;i++){
            var totaal = uurprList[i]*aantalList[i];
            subtotaal +=totaal;
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            li.innerHTML=totaal;
            document.getElementById("lijntotaal").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
        }
        /*subtotaal en btwtotaal wegschrijven*/
        document.getElementById("subtotaal").innerHTML=subtotaal;
        document.getElementById("btwbedrag").innerHTML=(subtotaal*0.21);
        document.getElementById("totaal").innerHTML=(subtotaal*1.21);
    }

    function verwijder(index){
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
            idlist[i+3].splice(index, 1);
        }
        print();
    }
} );

    })(jQuery);
```

And the HTML code that worked

```
    <body>




    <div class="page">
    <header class="header">

</header>

<div role="main" class="cf">
  <div class="container" id="factuur">
    <section id="header">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h1>Factuur</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">Factuur nr. 1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <div>Naam onderneming<br />
        Straatnaam nr<br />
      Postcode Gemeente<br />
    BE 0123 456 789</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>Naam Klant<br />
        Straatnaam nr<br />
      Postcode Gemeente<br />
      BE 0123 456 789</div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section id="content-header">
      <div class="col-sm-6">Omschrijving</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Uurprijs</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Aantal</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Totaal</div>
    </section>
    <section id="content">
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="omschrijving"><ul></ul></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="uurprijs"><ul></ul></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="aantal"><ul></ul></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="lijntotaal"><ul></ul></div>
    </section>
    <section id="totalen">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-3 text-right">Subtotaal</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="subtotaal"></div>

      <div class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-3 text-right">BTW</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="btw">21 %</div>

      <div class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-3 text-right">BTW Bedrag</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="btwbedrag"></div>

      <div class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-3 text-right" style="border-top:1px solid black;">Totaal</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="totaal" style="border-top:1px solid black;"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="factuurknop">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#factuurModal">
        Voeg een factuurlijn toe
      </button>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>


</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="factuurModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Voeg een factuur item toe</h4>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input style="width:30%" type="text" name="formOmschrijving" id="formOmschrijving" placeholder="Omschrijving">
          <input style="width:30%" type="text" name="formUurprijs" id="formUurprijs" placeholder="Uurprijs">
          <input style="width:30%" type="text" name="formUren" id="formUren" placeholder="uren">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="factuurFormSend" class="btn btn-primary">Verzenden</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("factuurFormSend").onclick = addLine;
      var omschList=[];
      var uurprList=[];
      var aantalList=[];
      var idlist=["omschrijving",
                  "uurprijs",
                  "aantal",
                  omschList,
                  uurprList,
                  aantalList]
    function addLine(){
        omschList.push(document.getElementById("formOmschrijving").value);
        uurprList.push(document.getElementById("formUurprijs").value);
        aantalList.push(document.getElementById("formUren").value);
        print()
    }

        /*print de lijnen verticaal uit*/
    function print(){
        for (var j =0;j<3;j++){
            document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML="";
            for (var i = 0; i<omschList.length;i++){
                var li = document.createElement("LI");
                if (j==0){
                    li.innerHTML = (idlist[j+3][i]+"<object align=\"right\" onclick=\"verwijder("+i+")\"><u>verwijder</u></object>");
                } else {
                    li.innerHTML = (idlist[j+3][i]);
                }
                document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
            }
        }
        /*bereken lijntotaal*/
        document.getElementById("lijntotaal").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML=""
        var subtotaal=0;
        for (var i=0; i<uurprList.length;i++){
            var totaal = uurprList[i]*aantalList[i];
            subtotaal +=totaal;
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            li.innerHTML=totaal;
            document.getElementById("lijntotaal").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
        }
        /*subtotaal en btwtotaal wegschrijven*/
        document.getElementById("subtotaal").innerHTML=subtotaal;
        document.getElementById("btwbedrag").innerHTML=(subtotaal*0.21);
        document.getElementById("totaal").innerHTML=(subtotaal*1.21);
    }

    function verwijder(index){
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
            idlist[i+3].splice(index, 1);
        }
        print();
    }
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). **What** does not work anymore? What does your code do, what does it not do and what should it do?

Comment: Also how do you load the separate file? And what is the file structure. If your code works in the html file itself then the problem is probably in the import of the file.

Comment: the onclick "verwijder" function must delete the generated line of code in the html table, but it doesn't recognise the function "verwijder" while if i put the script in the html code, it delete the line

Comment: the rest of the code in the file works, and i tried to load the file at the end of the html page, but it still doesn't recognise the function.Uncaught ReferenceError: idlist is not defined

Comment: Can you show us how you add the code via an external .js-file?

Comment: i deleted that code, but i selected "script" from tag name, took the last of child, and in innerhtml added the code

Comment: if `idlist` is not defined you need to define it before running the function. What is idlist? That part is not in your code.

Comment: idlist is a list with the idnames, because i needed to run the same code with different id

Comment: Can you maybe add both versions of your code to the question? The one that works, the one that does not and maybe also your HTML?

Comment: With what is idlist, I ment to say. What is the code of the defenition of idlist. And when is it executed. You will need to share the code if we need to help you.

Comment: Offtopic: Since you're working with money, be careful of rounding issues if you're adding calculations using a division later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your functions in the global scope if you want to assign the click events inline. Not in the load event handler.

*Better would be is not to add the click event inline but use event delegation for it. jQuery has great tools for this. Also your code is a weird combination between plain javascript and jQuery functions. It will work, but in my opinion it's better to stay to one style for readability*

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    /* VIEWPORT FIXES (http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/) */
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
      var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style');
      msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
          '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'
        )
      );
      document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }    

    document.getElementById("factuurFormSend").onclick = addLine;

  });

  function addLine() {
    omschList.push(document.getElementById("formOmschrijving").value);
    uurprList.push(document.getElementById("formUurprijs").value);
    aantalList.push(document.getElementById("formUren").value);
    print()
  }
})(jQuery);

var omschList = [];
var uurprList = [];
var aantalList = [];   
var idlist = ["omschrijving",
  "uurprijs",
  "aantal",
  omschList,
  uurprList,
  aantalList
]

/*print de lijnen verticaal uit*/
function print() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < omschList.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("LI");
      if (j == 0) {
        li.innerHTML = (idlist[j + 3][i] + "<object align=\"right\" onclick=\"verwijder(" + i + ")\"><u>verwijder</u></object>");
      } else {
        li.innerHTML = (idlist[j + 3][i]);
      }
      document.getElementById(idlist[j]).getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  /*bereken lijntotaal*/
  document.getElementById("lijntotaal").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].innerHTML = ""
  var subtotaal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < uurprList.length; i++) {
    var totaal = uurprList[i] * aantalList[i];
    subtotaal += totaal;
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    li.innerHTML = totaal;
    document.getElementById("lijntotaal").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(li);
  }
  /*subtotaal en btwtotaal wegschrijven*/
  document.getElementById("subtotaal").innerHTML = subtotaal;
  document.getElementById("btwbedrag").innerHTML = (subtotaal * 0.21);
  document.getElementById("totaal").innerHTML = (subtotaal * 1.21);
}

function verwijder(index) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    idlist[i + 3].splice(index, 1);
  }
  print();
}
```

If you want to be able to delete an object on click you could do this with jQuery and event delegation pretty easily.

```js
//Wait till the initial DOM loading is done
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Attach an event handler to the click event to the button the adds a new object
  $("#addObject").on('click', function() {
    $('#staticParent').append("<div class='deletableObject'>deletable on click</div>")
  });

  //Attach event delegation from the element with id staticParent to place a function on
  //the click event of all elements with the class deletableObject inside the element with
  //id staticParent. Because it's event delegation it will work also for elements with this
  //class the will be added later dynamicly.
  $("#staticParent").on('click', '.deletableObject', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="staticParent" style="min-height: 100px">
  <div class="deletableObject">deletable on click</div>
</div>
<button id="addObject">Add</button>
```

Comment: Edited the answer, you also need some variables in the global scope because of the inline event deceleration.

Comment: Also made an example how you can do deletion of object really easy in jQuery with event delegation. Assuming your `verwijder()` function needs to do something like that.

Comment: if I implement the code that you first posted, then the codeline: document.getElementById("factuurFormSend").onclick = addLine; doesn't work anymore. I will try to implement your jquery code.

Comment: Placed the add function back to your defined scope. But yeah It would be a lot better to place everything in your defined scope including attaching of event handlers.